# Full Screen Image Only Takes Up Top 1/3

Tags: html, css

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway')
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald')
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.intro {
 height: 100%;
 width:100%;
 margin: auto;
 background: url(https://static.pexels.com/photos/26206/pexels-photo.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
 display: table;
 top: 0;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Full Screen Landing Page
 </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
 <section class="intro">
  <div class="inner">
   <div class="content">
    <h1>Breathe Easy
    </h1>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Get Started
    </a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, alique
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, alique
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, alique
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

> When I open index.html in chrome the body only occupies the top 1/3 of the screen. It appears to run fine on stackoverflow, however. Why is this happening? My intention is to make a responsive full screen landing page. Thanks.

Comment: Runs fine in codepen as well. background-size: cover; should do the trick so... The only thing I would change is display: block; instead of table

Comment: Actually your `.intro` isn't 100% because the styles for the html and body tags are ignored you need a `;` semicolon after the import rules ...

Comment: @DaniP you are right thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you want the background to take up 100% of the space, apply the background image to the `body` element, not `#intro`. `#intro` is only as high as your content, so the background only covers that height.

Answer (score -1):

Add `100%` height and width to the body:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Another solution is to add `100vh` to the class `.intro`

```
intro {
  height: 100vh;
}
```